Нужно ли ставить тире перед словом «помощника»?
Подскажите, нужно ли в этом случае ставить тире:
Дело рассмотрено с участием представителя административного истца - помощника прокурора района Иванова И.И.
Или тире здесь неуместно?

Правильно:
Дело рассмотрено с участием представителя административного истца — помощника прокурора района Иванова И.И.
Пояснение
В данном случае представителем истца (административной власти) является прокурор, то есть можно вставить а именно.
Другого варианта оформления нет. Приложение является распространенным, то есть его нужно обособить. Запятая не подойдет, так как здесь не уточнение, а основная информация.
Розенталь, пункт 10 (1)

При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире: 1) если перед приложением можно вставить слова а именно (без изменения смысла).

Также можно учесть, что приложение выражает болееконкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет значение общее (см. примечание, пункт 2).
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
"Административный истец" – лицо, которое обратилось в суд в 
 защиту своих прав, свобод, законных интересов, либо лицо, в 
 интересах которого подано заявление прокурором, органом, 
 осуществляющим публичные полномочия, должностным лицом или 
 гражданином, либо прокурор, орган, осуществляющий публичные 
 полномочия, или должностное лицо, обратившиеся в суд для 
 реализации возложенных на них контрольных или иных 
 публичных функций (статья 38 Кодекса административного 
 судопроизводства Российской Федерации).

Административное судопроизводство в РФ отличается от гражданского и имеет свой кодекс.
Гражданский кодекс регулирует правовые отношения меду частными лицами, а административный связан с деятельностью органов власти. По административному иску свою правоту доказывает Ответчик (к нему предъявлен иск),  по гражданскому — Истец (он предъявляет иск). Также к особенностям административного иска  можно отнести значительно более короткие сроки рассмотрения Судом.
